# C#9 + .NET5, nullable enabled: is it possible to use the object initialiser with non nullable properties without using null!?

Tags: .net-5, c#-9.0

I'm testing c# 9.0 with NET 5.0 and there is something I don't understand. I enabled `<nullable>enable</nullable>`.

If I write a class

```
public class Potato {
    public string Colour { get; set;  }

    public string Flavour { get; set; }
}
```

I get the warning `CS8618: Non-nullable propery 'Colour' must contain a non-null value when existing constructor. Consider declaring the propery as nullable.` I do NOT want to declare it nullable, that's why I enabled the tag...

Then, I declare the constructor:

```
public class Potato
{
    public Potato(string colour, string flavour)
    {
        this.Colour = colour;
        this.Flavour = flavour;
    }

    public string Colour { get; set; }

    public string Flavour { get; set; }
}
```

So far so good. Now I want to create a `Potato` object using the object initialiser:

```
var sweetPotato = new Potato { 
    Colour = "orange",
    Flavour = "tasty",
};
```

And now I get the complain `CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'colour' of 'Potato.Potato(string, object)`. So, it tries to use the constructor I explicitly declared but I didn't introduce the parameters. I should do:

```
var sweetPotato = new Potato(
    colour: "orange",
    flavour: "tasty");
```

but here I am not using the object initialiser.

Another option would be declaring the class as

```
public class Potato
{
    public string Colour { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Flavour { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

with the `null!` elements, but this allows some weird things like:

```
var sweetPotato = new Potato()
{
    Colour = "orange",
};
```

which I think it is extremely weird. I declared 2 non nullable properties and thanks to the `null!` I can load the object with one property but not loading the second one. That breaks my nullable tag!

Then my question is: is it possible to use the object initialiser with non nullable properties if the nullable tag is enabled?

If it is not, I think that for classes with non nullable properties, without any `null!` involved, the default constructor should not be the empty one but the one with all arguments, and it should have to be possible to init an object with the object initialiser form, as long as all non-nullable properties are initialised.

Comment: What you did was make everything *non*-nullable unless explicitly tagged to be nullable with `?`. If you want the old behavior remove the `nullable` setting.

Comment: As for the rest of the question, most of it are attempts to use invalid syntax - if you specify a constructor, you *have* to use it and provide all parameters. This isn't affected by the `nullable` tag. You *can* use object-initializer syntax with all classes. If the class has no default constructor though, you *have* to use one of the constructors

Comment: The code you tried looks a lot like a `record` by the way. Except for the rather weird attempt to store an anonymous type as an opaque `object` that nobody can use afterwards. You can't use `.Flavour.Tasty` because `object` has no `Tasty` property. You can't cast it to a specific type either, because it contains an anonynous type. You should either make `Potato` a generic class or use `dynamic` for `Flavour`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @PanagiotisKanavos. 1) I wrote "non-nullable" when I meant "I do NOT want to declare it nullable". I fixed it. Sorry for the confusion. 2) The object thing is irrellevant. I changed it with a string. 3) Records can be mutable, but they are they are primarily built for better supporting immutable data models. In my case, I'll need to change the properties. 4) The core of my question is still not clear: how can I use object-initializer syntax on a class with non nullable elements? If I do not specify the constructor I get CS8614 and if I specify it, I must use it...

Comment: Short answer is no, the language doesn't support required initialized properties. You might want to keep your eyes on this proposal: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3630

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old Question but here's the comprehensive answer:

1. by adding the `<nullable>true<nullable>` tag you make it so that all nullables must be identified with `?`
2. because of 1., and since you didn't add `?` to their types, neither `Colour` nor `Flavour` can be `NULL`
3. because of 2., you must supply a constructor that initializes values for both `Colour` and `Flavour` - the default parameterless constructor won't work as it does nothing by itself and would return an object with `NULL` in both `Colour` and `Flavour`, as that's the default for their types, which you requested the compiler not to allow

The snippet below:

```
var sweetPotato = new Potato { 
    Colour = "orange",
    Flavour = "tasty",
};
```

uses the default parameterless constructor and so cannot be used. It is the shorthand equivalent to:

```
var sweetPotato = new Potato(); // sweetPotato has Colour and Flavour NULL
sweetPotato.Colour = "orange";  // sweetPotato still has Flavour NULL
sweetPotato.Flavour = "tasty";
```

which as you can see would create the object first (with default values) and assign values later. But by your not allowing the default value of `NULL`, it fails

And this is why if you won't allow them to be nullable, you must add a constructor that initializes them, and you must use that constructor

This wouldn't apply if their types were of a primitive that has a different default - like an `int` or a `double`. In that situation, the default parameterless constructor would work. But by using types with a default value of `NULL`, (like `string` or any `object` derived type), you can either make them nullable by adding `?` or you must use a constructor that initializes them to something other than `NULL`.

**Late, Late Edit**
You can use the object initializer still if you introduce a parameterless constructor that defaults those two properties:

```
public Potato()
{
     Colour = "blue";
     Flavor = "bitter";
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var bitterPotato = new Potato(); //blue and bitter potato
var sweetPotato = new Potato
{
    Color = "orange",
    Flavour = "tasty"
}; // orange and tasty potato
```

Comment: Yes, I see it, but the point is that I don't see the reason of using the default parameterless constructor of a class with non nullable elements. If `Colour` and `Flavour` are required and there is a constructor with these arguments, I guess that the default constructor of this object initialiser should use this constructor. Using the parameterless is kind of a contradiction!

Comment: @xavier - but you're activelly telling him not to use the constructor with parameters by not giving him parameters - like i said `var sweetPotato = new Potato { ... };` means use the parameterless constructor and then assign values. To use the non parameterless constructor you need to give him the parameters, i.e.: `var sweetPotato = new Potato("orange", "tasty");`

Answer (score 1):

The default value for `string` is null. As your property declarations do not define a default value, they will default to `default`, which happens to be `null` in the case of `string`. The problem is that you have not declared the type as `nullable`.

The solution is to assign a default value, such as `String.Empty`:

```
public class Potato
{
    public string Colour { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    public string Flavour { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I declare a field as non-nullable, I see writing an empty strings something like "cheating". If I want to force this property to have a value, "empty" is not really a value... :-(